# Standard Zip 2.0 encryption with ZipArchive

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, zip

I successfully created zip file with password using ZipArchive ([https://github.com/mattconnolly/ZipArchive](https://github.com/mattconnolly/ZipArchive/issues/36)). However, as my understanding, there is only one encryption method used that is aes 256. How to create a zip file with a password using the Standard Zip 2.0 encryption?

Comment: I used 7-zip and set the encryption method to "ZipCrypto", not AES, and Matt's ZipArchive can unzip it in iOS